# SAS: remove rows where value has already appeared

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with two columns of IDs, ID_A and ID_B.  Each row contains two ID's that I believe belong to the same person.  Because of this, each combination shows up twice.  For example:

```
ID_A   ID_B
A      B
C      D
B      A
D      C
```

What I want is to remove the repetition.  I.E. If I have the row A, B I don't require the row B, A.

```
ID_A   ID_B
A      B
C      D
```

Any idea how to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this...

```
data have;
   input (ID_A ID_B)($);
   cards;
A      B
C      D
B      A
D      C
;;;;
   run;
data haveV / view=haveV;
   set have;
   call sortc(of id:);
   run;
proc sort nodupkey out=want;
   by id:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @data *null* answer is perfect and robust. You can also try proc sql as shown below

```
    proc sql;
    create table want as 
    select distinct
    case when ID_A le ID_B then ID_A else ID_B end as ID_A,
    case when ID_A ge ID_B then ID_A else ID_B end as ID_B
    from have;
```